# Bootstrap Image Gallery - custom CSS preloader

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, blueimp

I'm using Bootstrap Image Gallery and Blueimp Gallery on my site. I wanted to change standard gallery preloader that is gif to simple CSS preloader. Can anyone tell how to make it properly? I tried, but it didn't work properly.

This kind of spinning wheel preloader is what I want to add instead of gif.
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/

Answer (score 0):

```
.blueimp-gallery > .slides > .slide-loading {
  background: url(../img/loading.gif) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 64px 64px;
}
```

defined in https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.css

You can copy and edit this and put it to your custom css, linked after the Bootstrap Image Gallery.

Comment: I think this is the right place to add preloader for image gallery: `.blueimp-gallery > .slides > .slide-loading {
 background: url(../images/preloader.gif) center no-repeat;
 background-size: 64px 64px;
}` But this code of preloader works withe some bugs: `width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 4px solid #f3f3f3;
 border-top-color: #3498db;
 -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 1s linear infinite;`

Comment: Yeah, you're right! What seems to be problem with that?

Comment: Actually a lot of other functionalities are working with bugs now.

Comment: Had a look in the js file and the thumbnail/picture box is made only with one div,which will later show the picture (it has set properties by other classes). Until then the div has class .slide-loading,which is removed as soon as the picture is loaded.By default the loader is a gif background, centered,no repeat, so there is no interference of loader and div. The solution would be to nest loader div into the picture div, but that's digging in the gallery JS.You can try width: 60px!important; height: 60px!important; but there are more styles applied and you won't be able to position it properly